# Gstreamer Playbin could not determine type of stream

Tags: c, gstreamer, playbin2

I am currently trying to create an audio application in linux using gstreamer 1.0. THe main issue I'm having is that running

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="file:///home/root/Documents/MP3/songs/test.mp3"
```

results in an error,

```
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind: Could not determine type of stream.
Additional debug info:
gsttypefindelement.c(1067): gst_type_find_element_loop (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

I have the mad plugin installed which is my audio decoder. some plugins i have installed:

```
playback:  playbin: Player Bin 2
playback:  playsink: Player Sink
playback:  streamsynchronizer: Stream Synchronizer
playback:  decodebin: Decoder Bin
playback:  uridecodebin: URI Decoder
mad:  mad: mad mp3 decoder
```

If I run

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp3 ! mad ! pulsesink
```

the audio runs flawlessly but I want to get playbin to work. Any experienced gstreamer users know whats going on?

Comment: This is off topic here and should be on [su].

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a configuration issue. In any case rerun with GST_DEBUG="*:3" and check if there are any warnings. The commands as such are fine and this is expected to work.